# Como leer archivo binario con C++

Tags: c++

Luego de mucho trabajo logre escribir y generar un archivo binario, pero cuando quiero leerlo me salen caracteres raros y no lo que genere, lo raro es que al final de la funcion de escribir el archivo, luego de cerrar, abro y puedo leerlo correctamente pero no desde otro lado.

```
FILE *infile;
paisesBolillero input;

infile = fopen ("paisesBolillero.dat", "rb");
if (infile == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
    exit (1);
} else {
    cout << "Se abrio" << endl;
}

while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct paisesBolillero), 1, infile)) {
    cout << "PAIS: " << input.pais << endl;
    cout << "BOLILLERO: " << input.bolillero << endl;
    cout << "CONFEDERACION: " << input.confederacion << endl;
    cout << "GRUPO: " << input.grupo << endl;
    cout << "LIBRE: " << input.libre << endl;   
    cout << " - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -" << endl;
}

fclose(infile);
```

Esa es la funcion que tengo, no funciona si el programa arranca queriendo leer el archivo, pero si funciona si lo leo despues de generarlo.

Que puede ser?

Comment: No entiendo, quiero leer el archivo .dat y luego listar los registros, nada mas

Comment: Solucionado, lo que hice fue cambiar el struct, los campos string los reemplace por char y le asigne un tamaño, nada mas

Comment: Agregalo como respuesta para los futuros visitantes

Comment: Solucionado, lo que hice fue cambiar el struct, los campos string los reemplace por char y le asigne un tamaño.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición del objeto `paisesBolillero`?